# sitecore configure / Insert options (roles, access setting?)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

On sitecore cms UI, there is a configure toolbar at the top that is available sometimes and sometimes not.  This toolbar allow me to set Insert Options, but is not available.   I am trying to figure out what access setting or user role controls whether this is visible?

Also, can I force parent Insert Options to all children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least the `Sitecore Client Authoring` or `Sitecore Client Designing` role to get access to the Configure ribbon.
Then you also need access to the chunks inside that ribbon.
From what i can see, you need the `Sitecore Client Developing` role for that.

So the quickest way is to give the user those three roles.

If you want control over which parts of the ribbon are accessible by a specific role, you can set Read rights in the Access Viewer for children of `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks` in the **Core** database.

Comment: I gave myself access to all of those and still no love. I went ahead and gave myself access to all client roles and I tweaked the security settings on insert and insert options and still no love.

Comment: You don't see the chunk at all, or is it only disabled? I have tried to reproduce it, but when i create a user with the roles Client User+ Authoring+Desigining+Developing it works okay. Only thing i noticed is the chunk is disabled if you don't have write access to the items.

Comment: I don't see the chunk at all for a specific media folder.  The media folder started off as a system folder but I changed the template because they didn't have the upload file insert option, but never got the correct insert options.  I'd love to just propagate this out easily rather than adjusting individual insert options to tell you the truth.  I've never had any formal sitecore training, just learning on the job, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The UI for sitecore is all defined in the core database, and the security settings on those items determine who can access them.

Switch to the core db on the sitecore desktop and check out /sitecore/content/applications/content editor and its children. (I'm not at a computer so that's not necessarily precise, but it should be close). You're probably looking for a ribbon item to set security on.

Good luck :)